# test spring cloud GateWay by MockMvc can't initialize a bean of type 'WebApplicationContext'

Tags: testing, junit, spring-cloud, gateway, mockmvc

The major problem description is below
`[a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext' that could not be found]`

I try many times,and guess adding a spring-boot-web-starter may works,but when i do that,another problem occured.

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or add more detailed code snippets on what you have tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use servlet based solutions with Spring Cloud Gateway since it's reactor based. Please use WebFlux starter instead of `spring-boot-web-starter`.

Comment: Many thanks.And any tool to test Gateway's response when visit a url,just like MockMVC test servlet based web app?